# jQuery validation method is never being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I know I've been asking about jQuery validation a lot lately, but I think I have my problem boiled down to the bare essentials now.

So if I have this HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>validation test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="theform">
        <div id="num" name="num">86</div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        var validationObject = {
            rules: {
                num: {
                  numtest:true
                }
            }
        };

        $.validator.addMethod("numtest", function(value, element) {
            return value == 42;
         });

        $('form').validate(validationObject);
        if ($("form").valid())
            alert("VALID");
        else
            alert ("INVALID");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I expect the alert to be `"INVALID"` because `num` is 86 instead of 42. But instead I get `"VALID"`; the function I defined to do the validation is not being called (I set a breakpoint on `return value == 42;` and it never gets hit). Why is this? How can I make sure the validation function gets called?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin but you're trying to perform validation on a `div` which isn't a form element

Comment: Yeah, the actual code I'm writing, it's a bit of a weird situation where I want to validate that a bunch of dropdowns all add up to the value in a div. So that's why I'm validating the div. But even if I change it to a text field, it still won't work...

Comment: Impossible.  Changing to `input type='text'` fixes it:  https://jsfiddle.net/c38uxh6m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're missing a validation error message in the custom method.  You should also use `this.optional(element)` so that you can leave the field empty and use the `required` rule separately.  *(The  way you had it written, the field would also be mandatory.)*

   ```
   $.validator.addMethod("numtest", function(value, element) {
       return this.optional(element) || (value == 46);
   }, "validation error message");
   ```
2. Put the whole thing inside a `ready` handler, which ensures the form exists before the `.validate()` method is called.  *(However, this is not what was breaking your form because JavaScript was called after the HTML.)*
3. This plugin does not recognize a `div` because it is not a valid form input element.  Change it to an `<input />`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element.

   ```
   <input type="text" id="num" name="num" />
   ```

Item #3 was the only thing that would break your code.

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/c38uxh6m/](https://jsfiddle.net/c38uxh6m/)**

Please carefully review the [SO Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) and the multitude of online examples.